# how to use Pyplot module of matplotlib to plot two arrays of data

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I wrote this code:
I wrote this code:
I am trying to plot the two arrays x "the data number" and y "the data itself"

```
for t in range(1, 281):
    data[t] = (3600 + (240 + t * 4) + 281)

for r in range(1, 281):
    sn[r] = r
x = np.array(sn[r])
y = np.array(data[t])
plt.plot(x, y)
```

where is the problem

Comment: Add `plt.show()` to actually show the plots.

Answer (score 5):

After plotting the data with `plt.plot(x,y)` you need to show the plot with `plt.show()`.  Alternatively you can save the plot directly to disk with `plt.savefig("Myfile.png",format="png")`.

Comment: Thanks, I knew that it will be something simple. Thanks so much.